# Форматирование кода в Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Возможно ли автоформатирование кода (HTML, CSS) средствами Netbeans?

Comment: Да, вот только код HTML вытянутый в одну строку никаким образом не форматирует

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно же, да.

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> — автоформатирование кода.

**[Топ-10 горячих клавиш в Netbeans](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.ru/2008/04/top-10-netbeans-ide-keyboard-shortcuts.html)**